# r - How to specify the path in normalizePath, or get around this error associated with it?

Tags: r

I'm learning R and just have it installed on my office computer. I don't have the administrator right on the computer (as I even have to call IT for installation).

Then I install a package. At first it doesn't work when typing, for example:

```
install.packages("thepackage")
```

The error message is this:

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="\\company\5050\Users\myusername\Documents\R\win-library\3.3": Access is denied
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\company/5050/Users/myusername/Documents/R/win-library/3.3": Access is denied
```

I do some homework and find that a potential solution is to "Map a network drive to your network folder". I'm not sure what it means, but I try this:

```
install.packages("thepackage",lib="H:/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")
```

because it looks like I have more "control" of H drive (it has my username on it). And it works:

```
package ‘thepackage’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4MNURu\downloaded_packages
```

I then fail to load the package,

```
library(thepackage)
```

saying:

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="\\company/5050/Users/myusername/Documents/R/win-library/3.3": Access is denied
```

But again this works:

```
library(thepackage,lib="H:/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")
```

So how can I set the normalizePath to the one that works to avoid additional and rather unnecessary specification of library directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put in your home directory's `.Rprofile` file (just create it if it's not there yet) the following line:

```
.libPaths("H:/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")
```

That way this location will be used by default. The `.Rprofile` is run every time you're opening any new R session. You can copy the existing content of the folder from which you don't have write access to this folder to include all pre-installed packages.

Comment: Thank you and @Konrad. I change the directory using .libPaths("path") and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

```
system("net use D: \\\\company\\path\\")
```

to map to the virtual `D` drive. I would then use `file.path` when accessing the stuff on `D:`. It looks that you may benefit from changing R defalut library path in `Rprofile.site`, by adding the line:

```
.libPaths("Path to your libs")
```

When you type `.libPaths()` can you read and write to that directory with no problems?

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem them I found this solution by the user [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732049/change-home-directory-for-r/63497464#63497464?newreg=1472ef1810aa41d397478bd7d710a56e).

> In Windows 10/11 you can also set the R Home Directory just for R
> without changing your system HOME with a special environment variable
> **R_USER**. Adding this to your Environment Variables with the path you
> want for your R Home will set the R Home path without changing your
> system HOME. RStudio looks for R_USER first (and then moves on to
> HOME).

It worked for me.