# Change home directory for R

Tags: r, path

Somehow, my home and library directories in R got changed to a cloud location, which is messing up a bunch of paths, and now, I can't seem to change it back. When I type `path.expand("~")` in R, I get back `"C:/Users/MyName/OneDrive/Documents"`, but I was expecting to get `"C:/Users/MyName/Documents"`.

When I try `.libPaths()`, I get `"C:/Users/MyName/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"` and `"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"`, but I only want the latter.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio (thus now working with the most-recent versions of each), but the cloud path persists. I have seen posts elsewhere on SO about setting things in the .Rprofile file, but I don't think that's the right option, especially since the .Rprofile file would then have to be in a cloud location, which I don't want.

I have looked at my environment variables in the control panel (I'm on Windows 10) and looked at PATH, but there's nothing there that specifies the cloud directory, so I don't know where it's coming from.

How do I permanently change my home directory and also make sure that `.libPaths` is pointing to only the actual library directory?

Comment: Check your environment variable `HOME`

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: You might try _setting_ it to C:/Users/MyName/Documents

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I figured there was one simple thing that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on your windows environment variable `HOME`.  You need to reset `HOME` to the path that you want "C:/Users/MyName/Documents"

If you want to do that from within R, you can use:

```
Sys.setenv(HOME="C:/Users/MyName/Documents")
```

This change would not be permanent. If you wish to avoid doing this every time you run R, you could put the above statement in your .Rprofile file. There is a nice article on setting up your .Rprofile in the [RStudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf)

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention you are

- **in Windows 10**

- **you can also set the R Home Directory just for R without changing your system HOME with a special environment variable,**

  **`R_USER`**

Adding this to your Environment Variables with the path you want for your R Home will set the R Home path without changing your system HOME.
[RStudio looks for R_USER first (and then moves on to HOME)](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f).

Comment: Thank you. I followed [these instructions](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094235653-Setting-global-environment-variables-on-Windows) to add R_USER to my environment variables.

Comment: great :)  Yes, that is an important piece of the puzzle ~