# Rscipt.exe Access Denied

Tags: r, path, rstudio, rscript

I'm trying to create an Rscript-file from a script I wrote in RStudio. When I open the `Rscript.exe` I get the following error message :

```
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1] = "xy": Access Denied
```

How can I change the path `xy` in my RScript-File to another folder?

Thank you for your help

Cheers Lucas

Comment: Hey Lucas welcome to SO, would you mind posting the RStudio script so that we may observe the process of creating the file? Thanks

Comment: I think you can find the following answer useful.
" [r- How to specify the path in normalizePath, or get around this error associated with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429458/r-how-to-specify-the-path-in-normalizepath-or-get-around-this-error-associate)